# Include multiple SQL queries in one BigQueryInsertJobOperator Airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

The syntax looks like this,

```
configuration={

          "query": {
                    "query": "{% include ['query_2.sql'] %}",
                    "useLegacySql": False,
 }
```

Is there any way I can do it?

```
"query": "{% include ['query_2.sql', 'query_3.sql', 'query_4.sql'] %}"
```

Comment: How about making a task of DAG for each query and set the dependencies among them:  `q2 >> q3  >> q4` ?

Comment: Thank you JayTiger, I thought of doing it that way, however, I have around 20 SQL files (belongs to on task) to execute, and was looking for an alternative to passing all the files under one task ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

configuration={

```
      "query": {
                "query": "{% for f in ['query_1.sql','query_2.sql'] %}"
                          "{% include f %}"
                              ";"
                          "{% endfor %}",
                "useLegacySql": False }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure listing all the queries you need and then you call it like this:

```
        t1 = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id="exec_sp",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": f"CALL `{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET}.stored_procedure_name` ();", 
                "useLegacySql": False,
                "timeoutMs": 3600000,
            }
        }
        )
```